# Backbone add ? after page url when an error occurred

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, backbone.js, requirejs

I am experiencing a strange error when I run my code. I am using an application with Backbone.js and RequireJS. The problem arises when there is an error in the code (any), seems that a backbone or jquery redirect to the url existing adding a question mark ? at the end of the page name:

```
URL before the error: http://localhost/home#users
URL after the error : http://localhost/home?#users
```

This causes the page to refresh. Anyone know why this behavior?

This is my code:

```
  var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: { 
            'click button#lookUp':'lookUp'

        },
    lookUp: function(){
      //Force error to show the error calling a function does not exist
      this.triggerSomeError();
    }
  });
```

Router:

```
var navigate = function(url) {
    appRouter.navigate(url, {
      trigger: true
    });
}

var initialize = function(){
    appRouter = new AppRouter;
    Backbone.history.start();
}
```

Html:

```
<button class="alinear-btn btn btn-primary" id="lookUp">Imprimir</button>
```

Chrome developer console:

[image: Console log from Chrome]

Comment: There's nothing in Backbone or Requirejs that should do this by default; can you please share more of your code and give more detail on what this error actually is?

Comment: @NickTomlin This happen when I click in a button and some error occur inside the function it calls, if I add a preventDefault(), the redirection does not trigger. I'll edit my questionm shareing somo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common error that we've run into. You need to change your code to the following:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: { 
        'click button#lookUp':'lookUp'
    },

    lookUp: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //Force error to show the error calling a function does not exist
        this.triggerSomeError();
    }
});
```

By default an event object is passed to a function called from the events collection, and you need to use this to prevent the default behavior. You can name the parameter whatever. I just typically call it event to be explicit.

What you are actually suppressing here is the **default behavior** of that **button in the browser**, which is to do a **form submit**. When you do a **form submit** in the browser it tries to take everything that's in the form and **append** it on to the **url as query parameters**. In this case the button is not in any form and so it's basically appending nothing and just putting the question mark for the query parameters.

The reason you got down votes and the reason you're getting an error is because you didn't create a method in your view called `triggerSomeError()` so of course you're going to get an error on that. However that's completely independent and has nothing to do with what's going on with your url path.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already solved it  a few days ago like you say. Although, I'm confused why it's happening this in my code. It shouldn't happen. For other hand, the problem occur only when something goes wrong, that's why I put that error line in my code, that indeed I put it.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's only happening on an error. That question mark being placed in the url should happen every time the button is clicked and the default behavior isn't being suppressed would be my assumption.

Either way, glad you could get the issue solved.